# Alignment issue in the Documentation examples

Tags: bug, documentation, design, documentation-examples

In the documentation example section (Click on **+ Add Example** icon on any documentation page), there are two minor alignment issues.

1. The **Markdown Editing Help icon** has extra back ground color.
2. The water mark/place holder content is showing one line in Firefox and two lines in Chrome.

Firefox Browser - Version 50.0.2

[image: Firefox browser]

Chrome Browser - Version 51.0.2704.103 m

[image: Chrome browser]

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome 54.0.2840.99. It seems like the "help" button was forgotten.